# Will WordPress updates remove Gutenberg Additional Classes?

Tags: customization, css, block-editor, theme-customizer, updates

I’m attempting to customize Gutenberg column blocks on my front page.
I’ve added a custom class name to a column block using the blocks Additional CSS class feature.

[image: Gutenberg additional classes image]

In my child theme style sheet, I’ve added my custom CSS declarations to the block element that has the custom class I created. And this works fine.

My question is if a new WordPress update is issued, will the update remove all my Gutenberg additional classes?

Thanks in advance for any help with this question.

Comment: Everything you do with the Graphic interface of WordPress will stay in the DataBase, so no, the updates will not remove those changes, not the CSS you wrote or the custom class you gave to your block.

Comment: Thanks Laloptk !